# URL encoding give auth error when using azure blob rest api

Tags: curl, azure-blob-storage, azure-rest-api

I am using curl(inside bash script) to upload file using [PUT Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) to azure blob storage. When I URL encode the path to where I want the file to be stored like `"https://${endpoint}/${container_name}/a/b/c/te%20st.txt"` (original file name is "te st.txt") and I put the same path in my canonical resource string like `"/${account_name}/${container_name}/a/b/c/te%20st.txt"`, I get "AuthenticationFailed" error. I am using "Authorization: SharedKey ${account_name}:${signature}"

If I remove the % (and remove any spaces) it works like a charm. I tried escaping the % char with %2520 but does not work.

Authorization header is calculated as follows:

```
canonicalized_headers="x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:${date}\nx-ms-version:2019-07-07\n"

canonicalized_resource="/${account_name}/${container}/${key}"

string_to_sign="PUT\n\n\n${content_length}\n\n${contentType}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n${canonicalized_headers}${canonicalized_resource}"

decoded_hex_key="$(echo "$azure_key" | openssl enc -base64 -d)"

signature=$(printf "$string_to_sign" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt "key:$decoded_hex_key" -binary | openssl enc -base64)

curl -vvv -g -k --limit-rate "${rate_limit}" --proto-redir =https -X PUT -T "${file_name}" \
-H "x-ms-date: ${dateFormatted}" \
-H "${version}" \
-H "${blob_type}" \
-H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
-H "Authorization: SharedKey ${account_name}:${signature}" \
"https://${endpoint}/${container}/${key}"
```

When I put a %20 instead of a space in `key` I get `403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature`

I am using
blob_type=x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
version=x-ms-version:2018-03-28 (also tried the version 2019-07-07)

Any leads will be highly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question and include code for computing your Authorization header? I am interested in seeing how you're creating canonicalized resource string.

Comment: Done. Let me know if something is not clear. Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you provide canonical resource string as `"/${account_name}/${container_name}/a/b/c/te st.txt"`? Do you still get 403 error? Also, please include your complete curl command.

Comment: yeah if i do not url encode the resource string and URL encode the URL in curl i get 403. Even though the documentation says to keep the resource string exactly as URL encoded. Thanks. Added the curl command